# Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\UserProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

This is my auth.php file

```
return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'salon_emp',
        // 'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'salon_emp' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'salon_emp'
        ],

        'app' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'client'
        ]
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'salon_emp' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => SalonEmployee::class,
        ],
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Client::class
        ]
    ],
```

This is my login function in my `LoginController`

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (auth('app')->attempt($request->validated())) {
            auth('app')->user()->tokens()->delete();
            return apiResponse([
                'message' => 'Login successful!',
                'token' => auth('app')->user()->createToken(auth('app')->user()->name)->plainTextToken
            ]);
        } else {
            return apiResponse([
                'message' => 'Login not successful!',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
```

I am also using sanctum for authentication
in my routes file i am using the `auth:sanctum` middleware to secure my routs, for example:

```
Route::get('/test',function ()
{
    dd('ss');
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

how ever i get this error whenever i try to access it

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\UserProvider, null given, called in \vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php on line 128",
```

i have tried changing providers and drivers but no luck

Comment: you config auth, why app ( i presume it is api ) use driver session instead of token?

Comment: it is the api true. i am using the session driver as it has the attempt() function needed to validate the provided credentials in the login method.

Comment: @YehiaKhalis I see, I did not know that is even possible, I always use sanctum middleware for that , `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`

Comment: @Win didnt either. I was using the sanctum driver before and kept getting an error that the attempt() function doesnt exist on this driver untill i learned from [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/method-illuminateauthrequestguardattempt-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to sanctum.php

`'guard' => 'app'`

and it worked fine

Comment: Mark as correct later.